# Uninstall software

Tags: uninstall

I am an absolute newbie to Ubuntu.

I am running 12.04 64 bit. I installed PDF-Editor from Tracker software and now I would like to get it off this machine, but I can't figure out how to do it. I tried Tweak and Synaptic but it doesn't appear anywhere in those programs.

Can anyone help?

Comment: First, provide the steps you followed to install this software. __Edit__ your question to add this information.

Answer (score 2):

Some ways to remove software on Ubuntu:

- **Using the Ubuntu Software Center**: Search for the software in it, select the appropriate software and click on `remove`
- **Using the terminal:** Using the command `sudo apt-get purge [packagename]` where `[packagename]` is the excact name of the package you want to install. You could also use `sudo apt-get remove [packagename]` if you want to keep the settings of the package.